# What is this set of block matrices called?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, terminology, block-matrices

Let $S$ be the set of matrices defined inductively as follows:

- The scalar $1 \in S$.
- $M \in S$ if  $M$ is a $2 \times 2$ [block diagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) where the blocks are recursively in $S$.
- $M \in S$ if $M$ is a $2 \times 2$ block [anti-diagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) where the blocks are recursively in $S$.

Are there any special names / properties of $S$?

Comment: Why did you add the group theory tag? In other words, what is the motivation of this question? Just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any names, but maybe you can clarify what you're looking for in terms of properties.  (They have determinant $\pm 1$, but surely this much is obvious.  Another simple property is the product of any two elements of $S$ (of the same size) is block diagonal.)

The matrices in $S$ of size $2^n \times 2^n$ will be permutation matrices for permutations which one might call "bipartite," in the sense that it is either a product of a permutation on $\{ 1, \ldots, 2^{n-1} \}$ with one on $\{ 2^{n-1}+1 , \ldots, 2^{n} \}$,
or the composition of such a product with the permutation switching $i$ and $2^{n-1}+i$.
(In the latter case, the corresponding graph will be bipartite.)  Furthermore, each of the subpermutations is again of this "bipartite" type.

Consequently for each dimension $2^n$, the matrices in $S$ form a subgroup of $S_{2^n}$ (in general not abelian), and the order is easy to count: $2^{2^0+2^1+\cdots+2^{n-1}}=2^{2^n-1}$.  Examining the first few cases, suggest that these matrices in fact give a 2-Sylow subgroup of $S_{2^n}$.

Comment: If you have a group of matrices G, and a group of permutations H of degree n, then the **wreath product** of G with H is the group of n×n block matrices whose nonzero blocks are from G, and are in the positions described by H: the block in the *i* th row is in the π( *i* )th column.  In this case, H = { (), (1,2) }, and G becomes an iterated wreath product of copies of H, so indeed, a Sylow 2-subgroup of Sym(2^n).